# Is "Constraint" keyword required in Alter table Add [Constraint] syntax?

Tags: oracle, syntax, oracle11g, oracle10g, constraints

I came across an example with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD UNIQUE(col1)
```

Normally I would write

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(col1)
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_1 UNIQUE(col1)
```

for unnamed and named constraint.

My question is whether the keyword `CONSTRAINT` is required ? I could not find reference on this. Can we write

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD FOREIGN KEY(col1) REFERENCE T1(col2)
ALTER TABLE T ADD PRIMARY KEY(col1)
```

Comment: It should be **`REFERENCES`** not `REFERENCE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can use:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD FOREIGN KEY(col1) REFERENCES T1(col2);
ALTER TABLE T ADD PRIMARY KEY(col1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RIO30377)**</kbd>

or if you want to name them:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT fk_T_T1 FOREIGN KEY(col1) REFERENCES T1(col2);
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT pk_T PRIMARY KEY(col1);
```

[ALTER TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2192749):

[image]

<sup>Image from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img/constraint_clauses.gif</sup>

and:

[image]
<sup>Image from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img/out_of_line_constraint.gif</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the documentation (link below), the keyword CONSTRAINT is optional:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB

However, it is required if you want to name your constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The `constraint <constraint_name>` subclause is not required.